# how created new db in hqsl Database Manager?

Tags: database, hsqldb

I do not understand how to create a new database in hqsl Database Manager. [image: Here] I go to the old database (test), and as a new build?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. General "how do use software" questions are offtopic.

Comment: I know, but for begin programming i need to create new db but i dont know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the HSQLDB Server, it creates the database(s) that you list in the `server.properties` file. If you do not have this file or you do not specify a new database, a database, named test, is created.

If you use the `server.remote_open=true` property when you start the server, you can connect to a new database and it is created by the server. For example, the URL can be this:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/newtest;filepath=file:C:/files/mydatabase
```

Which creates the set of files for mydatabase and allows you to connect also with this URL

```
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/newtest
```

You cannot delete an existing database. But it is possible to drop the schema with all the tables and their data in the database.

See the Guide here:

http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/listeners-chapt.html